# representing if in c++ as a function

Tags: c++

Is there any way of writing If as a function in c++? 
I am not sure if I write my question correct.

```
int sum(int a, int b)
int total;
total = a + b;
return total;
```

So this is sum function, how can I write If in that way?

Comment: Could you show how you intend to use it? Also, your function is missing some braces `{}`. You may be able to get away with a predicate/function object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
void if_else(bool cond, std::function<void()> if_, std::function<void()> else_) {
    cond ? if_() : else_();
}
```

Even to there is still an if/else statement in the form of the ternary operator...

This one may be another solution:

```
void if_else(bool cond, std::function<void()> if_, std::function<void()> else_) {
    (cond && ([&]() { if_(); return true; })()) || else_();
}
```

I'm not sure about the second one, mainly because of the definition of a function immediately executed, but I guess the idea is pretty clear.

Comment: You are returning a value from a void function.

Comment: You are right, let me drop the return.